# PIC: Elements of array have incomplete type

Tags: c

I'm making a code for a PIC, after coding all the menu in english, I needed to include 2 more languages, so I converted my text arrays in matrix to include the other 2 languages.

```c
static const XCHAR sNo[3][] ={
                                    {"No"},
                                    {"No"},
                                    {"Non"}
};
```

After compiling it, the compiler gave me the following error:

> Strings.h:150: error: elements of array `sNo' have incomplete type.

Comment: Not sure if its a typo - you didn't specify the 2nd dimension size.

Answer (score 0):

The size of the "inner" array can not be deduced, you must specify its size explicitly:

```
static const XCHAR sNo[3][4] = { ... };  // 4 to fit three characters plus terminator
```

Comment: Maybe it is easier to use `XCHAR const* const sNo[] = { "No", "No", "Non" }`, one wouldn't have to care for string lengths this way...